# In Mughal India, which factors determined which countries were allowed forts?

Tags: economy, india, england, mughals

I'm roughly halfway through this excellent extensive book: [Anarchy: The Relentless Rise of the East India Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Anarchy_(book)). One of the more memorable sections to me was the account of how the first gestures the English made to build favor with [Jahangir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahangir). May of the gifts the English tried to give him fell flat on their face: carriages, art and a wide variety of other cultural artifacts were able to be reproduced and improved upon almost instantly by Jahangir.

As the book presents the process, the East India Company went from having, (from Jahangir's viewpoint) 'partially-educated' broken-Turkish-speaking handful of correspondents to an improved standing by learning Persian language and honing in on the areas of English culture that was of interest to the Mughal King. Over time, they were approved forts/factories in Madras, Calcutta and Kasimbazar.

The French also had forts; they managed to navigate the Mughal Court more adeptly.

But all the while the Armenians, which Dalrymple refers to periodically had no forts. Yet they had maintained a merchant community within the Mughal lands for centuries. They lived under the protection of the Mughals -- not in their own forts.

### Question

Dalrymple doesn't spell out exactly why it was that there was not equality of outcomes with the different foreign populations operating in Mughal India, so how may we most accurately connect the dots for ourselves: what are the major factors when it comes to lobbying successfully for a fortification on Mughal land?

After all, the Armenian peoples at during the 17th and 18th centuries were fairly renown for their linguistic skills and commercial ingenuity.

Comment: 1) The question seems to be about Armenians specifically, but the title doesn't indicate that. I would suggest changing the title and if there are any other groups to be examined, make a seperate question. 2) The question implicitly assumes that groups like the Armenians *wanted* to establish forts, but failed to negotiate the permission. Is there any evidence that this was the case? [They did have settlements.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25165093?seq=1)

Comment: One would imagine that the first step would be being the kind of people who would *want* forts.